# Is it possible to separate this print line so that it prints on separate lines instead of on one line?

Tags: python, printing, newline

```
your_name = input("Please tell me your name:  ")
your_age = int(input("Please tell me your age:  "))
print_times = int(input("How many times would you like to print this message? "))
years_old = 2023 + 100 - your_age
print(("Hi ", your_name + " ", "you will be 100 years old in ", years_old)  *  print_times)
```

Comment: Use "\n" wherever you want a newline.

Comment: Have you really never asked a question in 4 years as a member?

Comment: or use a for `loop` to call `print` several times instead of once...

Comment: @Matthias, but you have ***answered*** questions. I wouldn't have asked that if the OP had answered questions. I can't say whether or not a member of 4 years not asking or answering any questions is unusual, since I haven't looked at the data, but I would personally find it surprising, hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
print(("Hi ", your_name + " ", "you will be 100 years old in ", years_old)  *  print_times)
```

you can use a much more readable f-string with '\n' to separate the outputs:

```
print(f'Hi, {your_name}, you will be 100 years old in {years_old} \n' * print_times)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like *Joe* wrote, you can put `\n` at the end of your string. We're presuming that you want the new line after the number of years.

```
print("Hi " + your_name + ", you will be 100 years old in " + str(years_old) + ".\n" *  print_times)
```

or

```
greeting_msg = "Hi " + your_name + ", you will be 100 years old in " + str(years_old)
print_timesprint("\n".join([greeting_msg] * print_times)
```

Like *Rivka* wrote, string formatting could be more legible using an f-string or using the `str.format` method.

You could also just execute `print` multiple times.

```
greeting_msg = "Hi " + your_name + ", you will be 100 years old in " + str(years_old)
for _ in range(print_times):
    print(greeting_message)
```

Comment: Why only cite two of the three people?